# understanding code that removes duplicate characters in a string (from cracking the coding interview)

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Here is the question from "cracking the coding interview" Q1.3 "Design an algorithm and write code to remove the duplicate characters in a string without using any additional buffer. NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine. An extra copy of the array is not." and I wrote a program that seems to work well, but I am confused with my own program. Here is the code attached.

```
string remove_duplicates(string &s1)
{
   int n=s1.size();
   for(int i=n-1; i!=-1; --i)
        for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
        {
            if(s1[i]==s1[j])
            {
                int k=i;
                while(k!=n)
                {
                    s1[k]=s1[k+1];
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    return s1;
}
```

If s1=abcdeafg, the output will be abcdefg by using this code, (and if input is abababab, output will be ab)
But what I thought is that because the length of s1 does not change, the output should be abcdefga since I just move the second 'a' to the end of s1. Could you guys help me explain it?

Answer (score 2):

The length of s1 actually is changing. When you have found a duplicate character and are using  the while(k!=n) loop moving the duplicate character towards the end of s1, in the final iteration of the loop when k == n-1, the code is evaluating s1[n-1] = s1[n] and actually is s1[n-1] = '\0', so the length of s1 is shortened by 1.

Comment: Are you saying that the value of `size()` changes?

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, actually the size() of s1 hasn't changed from the beginning. But when you output a C++ string, it would stop until it reaches a NULL character, in other words, if you assign a string as "abcde" and then assign the 4th character of this string as '\0', if you try to use cout to output this string you'll find that the output is "abcd" instead of "abcde".

Comment: @derekhh: I'm not sure I buy that. Are you claiming that `std::cout << std::string("QR\0S", 4)` shall only print "`QR`"? (In that case, my compiler is broken.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: En, I've also found my comment is incorrect...It's just because '\0' character won't be ouputted...

Comment: On my compiler (and I'm sure as mandated by the standard), *everything* is "outputted" as you put it. It may be that your **terminal** doens't print a visible character, though. Try piping the result through `hexdump`, or into a file, to be certain.