# Can someone please explain this function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing a program to remove duplicate characters from a string and I already found the code, it was posted a year ago but there are a few things that I don't get. [understanding code that removes duplicate characters in a string (from cracking the coding interview)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11596220/4043493)

```
string remove_duplicates(string &s1)
{
   int n=s1.size();
   for(int i=n-1; i!=-1; --i)
    for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)         //why is j<i ?
    {
        if(s1[i]==s1[j])
        {
            int k=i;              //What does the k do?
            while(k!=n)           //Why do we use loop here?
            {
                s1[k]=s1[k+1];    //why is k=k+1 ?
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
return s1;
}
```

Comment: Run through a few simple examples by hand (i.e. draw a diagram of the contents of the array, and how it changes as the code progresses).

Comment: First of all it's a string, not an array. Second thing is, I already figured that out by myself and tried and when I did not know why, I asked the question. But thanks for sharing your opinion anyways :)

Comment: Also, this code doesn't actually work.

Comment: it DOES work, it's not a complete one of course, it's just a function obviously!

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't work properly: http://ideone.com/KYi3XX

Comment: It works for me, I wrote the complete code here http://ideone.com/WIgusj

Comment: Yes, and here is your code providing an incorrect answer: http://ideone.com/crfjYx.

Comment: It does, didn't you enter "abcabc"? and the answer was "abc"? That's what I want; removing duplicates!

Comment: But what about the reported size?

Comment: It counts the "enter" plus the letters.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It's broken, because it never actually shortens the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is correct.
Explanation given as inscribed comments.

```
string remove_duplicates(string &s1)
{
 int n=s1.size();
 for(int i=n-1; i!=-1; --i)
  for(int j=0; j<i; ++j) // need to check if s1[i] has repeat till i-1
  {
   if(s1[i]==s1[j]) // repeat found
   {
     int k=i;  // k stores the position of char repeated earlier
     while(k!=n) // till end of the original string
     {
      s1[k]=s1[k+1]; // left shift all chars from repeat char till null terminating char
      k++;
     }
   }
  }
  s1=s1.c_str();
  return s1;
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   string s = "abccbcd";
   cout << remove_duplicates(s).c_str() << endl;
   return 0;
}

Result is: "abcd" (size = 4)
```

"abccbcd" becomes "abccbd" then "abccd" then "abcd"

Comment: The function is not correct.  It doesn't modify the length of the string.

Comment: The modified size can be re-written but the aim of this function is to remove duplicate characters.. How can it shorten the string?

Comment: Edited my answer with a simple trick added, s1=s1.c_str(); before returning, now try, upvote pls :-)

Comment: @user4043493 edited answer takes care of the string length too